# Two exception gives an error in plsql block

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I need to return if there is any K status in table. When there is no K status it returns no row so INTO part gives error. Therefore, I added an exception and finally get 0 status_count but this time there is a final exception at the end of plsql block .

Should I return 0 when query returns no row OR I need to handle 2 exceptions? Any suggestions?

```
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_status_count 
    FROM tablename
    WHERE STATUS = 'K'
    AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER = o_account_number
    GROUP BY STATUS;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       v_status_count := 0;  

    IF v_status_count > 0 THEN
     o_status := 'Y';
    END IF;

 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     o_result := 1;
END;
```

Comment: Alex, it is not true, when you combine `count` with `group by` you can get zero rows, e. g. `select count(*) from dual  where dummy = 'Y' group by dummy`

Answer (score 1):

don't wat u are trying to achieve but ,

```
DECLARE 
    v_status_count NUMBER :=0;

    BEGIN


 SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_status_count 
        FROM tablename
        WHERE STATUS = 'K'
        AND ACCOUNT_NUMBER = o_account_number
        GROUP BY STATUS;


     EXCEPTION 
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
           v_status_count := 0;  

     WHEN OTHERS THEN
         o_result := 1;
    END;
```

Answer (score 1):

remove your `group by` clause, it is not needed in this case

Comment: I removed the group by. OK but still cant handle when returning no row. I can only handle it by catching NO_DATA_FOUND exception. I solved the conflict between final exception with my inner exception by surrounding my control with begin end.

Comment: please, provide full text of your procedure with its header

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's a bit unclear what you are looking for. In the example below I assume one would like to know if account number and status combination exists in database.

**Data setup**

```
create table accounts (
  account_number number,
  status varchar2(1)
);

insert into accounts values (1, 'K');
insert into accounts values (2, 'L');

select * from accounts;

ACCOUNT_NUMBER S
-------------- -
             1 K
             2 L
```

**Procedure**

```
create or replace procedure get_account_status(
  p_account_number in number,
  p_status in varchar2,
  o_status out varchar2,
  o_result out number
) is
  v_count number;
begin
  -- the select that never throws:
  -- v_count = 0 if no account with requested status found
  -- v_count = 1 if at least one row with account and status is found
  -- note rownum = 1 is valid restriction as it's enough to know that at least
  -- one row exists
  select count(*)
    into v_count
    from accounts
   where status = p_status
     and account_number = p_account_number
     and rownum = 1;

  -- adjust the return/output value(s) as you like
  if v_count = 1 then
    o_status := 'Y';
    o_result := 1;
  else 
    o_status := 'N';
    o_result := 0;
  end if;

end;
/
show errors
```

**Test block and results**

```
declare
  v_status varchar2(1);
  v_result number;
begin
  get_account_status(1, 'K', v_status, v_result);
  dbms_output.put_line('v_status = ' || v_status  ||
                       '; v_result = ' || v_result);

  get_account_status(2, 'K', v_status, v_result);
  dbms_output.put_line('v_status = ' || v_status  ||
                       '; v_result = ' || v_result);

  get_account_status(3, 'K', v_status, v_result);
  dbms_output.put_line('v_status = ' || v_status  ||
                       '; v_result = ' || v_result);
end;
/

v_status = Y; v_result = 1
v_status = N; v_result = 0
v_status = N; v_result = 0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```